# Is it ok to use display:none, for a responsive website, when views are too different?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm actually working on a responsive Website (with Wordpress). For responsiveness I usually use Bootstrap's grid, but this time the design mockup is completely different for the 2 views so there's no really good way to use Bootstrap here.

I was thinking of using `display:none` rule to switch view.

But my concern is: is it a good practice to do it because everything will be download twice for Mobile and Desktop view. If not: is there another way to do it?

Comment: if they are "too different", consider using device detection and print different html and styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the visibility classes that bootstrap has.
The table below is the best overview how it works.

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/

[image: Table]

Comment: Ok, I was not aware of this hidden feature in bootstrap, I might then use this. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Though its not recommended and consider as bad practice to use display none. But mostly try to avoid it. If possible, you can use media queries to adjust the styling for mobile views.

Comment: Avoid media queries please, look at the responsive utilities bootstrap already has